# Element scrolls to the top on hover in Chromium browsers

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css, chromium

In my **TailwindCSS** I have this template

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-screen min-h-screen ">
    <div class="flex max-h-full">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="flex flex-col-reverse overflow-auto">
                <div class="flex justify-end h-full max-h-full">
                    <div class="flex items-center group">
                        <div class="bg-gray-500 h-[2000px]">Hover here from a little down</div>
                        <div class="opacity-10 group-hover:opacity-100">Element of Group</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is supposed to move all element to the **bottom** of the page, from this point I apply a hover effect to turn `opacity-10` to `opacity-100`.

My observation and trials conclusion is that the template has to have:

1. **exact classes** while the **height** of `.group` being **very high**.
2. **Height** has to be above my maximum screen resolution height. **(doubtful about it)***
3. The **group** effect occurs with `opacity`, `display` or `font-size`. **(background doesn't)***
4. **Browser** has to be **Chromium Based**. (Doesn't occur in Firefox)

I was able to reproduce the abnormal behaviour using the template, and I tested it in a **Snippet**.

- It's supposed to be many blocks of `.group` instead of `h-[2000px]`
- The idea of the template is to have multiple of `.group` with
  `flex-col` on the **parent** while **keeping** the **scrollbar at the bottom** with
  dynamic appending.

I am looking to understand the behaviour. In case you've stumbled in it, the solution is to use `position: absolute`, or you can use **initial** `color` **equal** to **background** and **hover effect** to your desired **color**